# Text resolution blur in text editor and browser Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Tags: 20.04, fonts, text-editor

I just booted Ubuntu 20.04 but I do not understand why text resolution is blurred.
I tried to use tweak if it shows some changes but it doesn't help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's a problem with the Chrome browser fonts since both of your screenshots are related to Chrome. So adjust [your Chrome fonts](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/software/how-change-font-in-google-chrome-3606119/).

Comment: it dosenot work. I tried the same link in other browsers too. same problem. 

I try to inspect the font family see that when 'Monaco' font is creating this problem. I don't understand if this font is coming from  Ubuntu machine or from browser.

Comment: As far as I know there's no **Monaco** font family in ubuntu. At least in my 18.04 system there's not such a font.